# Como fazer uma busca em um arquivo xml com php?

Tags: php, xml

```
<ISBN id = "1">
        <genero>
            <descricao>
                Suspense
            </descricao>
            <descricao>
                Ficcao Policial
            </descricao>
        </genero>
        <titulo>
            Assassinato no expresso do oriente
        </titulo>
        <autor>
            Agatha Christie
        </autor>
        <publicacao>
            1934
        </publicacao>
    </ISBN>
```

Pessoal, quero criar um sistema em PHP para que baseado no arquivo xml acima, o usuário possa digitar, por exemplo, suspense e fazer uma busca por todos os livros com esse gênero. Alguém sabe como eu posso fazer isso? 
(O xml original é composto de  8 livros estruturados dessa forma)

Comment: Esse `XML` é gerado através de registros do banco de dados?

Comment: Estou fazendo em um arquivo local para estudo, carrego o xml da mesma pasta através do file_get_contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `SimpleXMLElement` para trabalhar com `XML` no `PHP`.

Ao utiliza-lo, você receberá um elemento com o método `xpath`. Com esse método você pode utilizar expressões para filtrar alguns valores, por exemplo:

```
$livros = $simpleXML->xpath("//genero//*[contains(text(), 'genero')]/../..");
```

Dessa forma nós acessamos todos os elementos `genero` e verificamos com `contains`, se o texto possui o genero desejado. Depois retornamos ao nó `ISBN` com os `../../`

**Código completo:**

```
<?php

$pesquisa = "Assassinato";

$xml = <<<XML
<Livros>
    <ISBN id="978-8547216696">
        <genero>
            <descricao>Direito</descricao>
            <descricao>Psicologia</descricao>
        </genero>

        <titulo>
            Insania Furens. Casos Verídicos de Loucura e Crime
        </titulo>

        <autor>
            Guido Arturo Palomba
        </autor>

        <publicacao>
            2017
        </publicacao>
    </ISBN>

    <ISBN id="978-8594540386">
        <genero>
            <descricao>Psicologia</descricao>
        </genero>

        <titulo>
            Arquivos Serial Killers. Made in Brazil e Louco ou Cruel
        </titulo>

        <autor>
            Ilana Casoy
        </autor>

        <publicacao>
            2017
        </publicacao>
    </ISBN>

    <ISBN id="978-8594540133">
        <genero>
            <descricao>Histórias Reais</descricao>
            <descricao>Assassinato e Mutilação</descricao>
        </genero>

        <titulo>
            Casos de Família: Arquivos Richthofen e Arquivos Nardoni
        </titulo>

        <autor>
            Ilana Casoy
        </autor>

        <publicacao>
            2016
        </publicacao>
    </ISBN>
</Livros>
XML;

$simpleXML = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$livros = $simpleXML->xpath("//genero//*[contains(text(), '{$pesquisa}')]/../..");

foreach($livros as $livro) {
    $titulo = trim(reset($livro->xpath("./titulo")[0]));

    echo "Título: {$titulo}\n";
}
```

Comment: Sabe como eu imprimo varias tags com o mesmo titulo, por exemplo , no meu xml tem varias tags descrição aí seguindo o seu código iria imprimir apenas a de índice "0".

Comment: @EduardoRibeiro não entendi.